# I want to run Oracle 12c Form builder on Client Computers How it Possible?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

I want to run Oracle 12c form builder on multiple client machine same like 6i just install on client machine is it possible???

Answer (score 2):

Installing Oracle Forms 12 for design-time only (i.e. Builder) is simple and can be done in a matter of minutes.  Simply download the software titled "Forms and Reports" (currently version 12.2.1.4) and run the installer.  Note that the installer must be launched in an elevated session, meaning right click on setup.exe and select "Run as administrator".  This is not the same as being a member of the Windows Administrator group.

When prompted, choose the option "Standalone Forms Builder.

[image: Standalone Forms Builder]

This installation includes all the tools and utilities needed to develop a complete Forms application.  It does not include the Forms runtime engine or Reports Builder.  To get the runtime engine(s) and Reports Builder a full installation is needed.

Although a full installation does require several steps, it too can be completed in just a few minutes.  This is all explained in the Installation Guide, but here is a summary of steps:

1. Download and install Oracle Java JDK (64-bit) 8u<*latest*>
2. Download and install Fusion Middleware Infrastructure 12.2.1.4
3. Download and install Forms and Reports 12.2.1.4 into the same home created for step 2
4. Run Repository Creation Utility
5. Run Configuration Wizard
6. Start servers (Node Manager, Admin Server, WLS_FORMS)

Assuming all you want is "Forms", you are done.  For Reports there are a couple post config steps, but these are trivial to complete.

All the software and documentation needed is linked from the Oracle Forms product page.

https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/forms/forms.html

And don't forget about the Oracle Forms Community Forum.  There you can interact directly with Oracle employees, customers, and many others.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/forms

And for the record, Forms 6i (6.0.8) supported "character mode", "client/server", and "web (three tier)" deployment.  Starting with Forms 9.0.2, only web was supported.